# Standard Action for all screens in Install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I'd like to setup an action which should be executed **asynchronously** every time a an installer screen is presented to the user.

Is there any way to do that (short of implementing it in Java)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with an installer event listener. Add a "Run script" action to the startup node with the following code:

```
context.addInstallerEventListener(new InstallerEventListener() {
    public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == EventType.SHOW_SCREEN) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Add your code here                    
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }    
});
return true;
```